WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error 400 (Bad Request)
  if (!publicKey) {
    alert("Please connect your wallet to continue.");
    return;
  }
  const userAccount = new UserAccount({
    owner: publicKey.toBytes(),
    is_initialized: true,
    userType: userType,
    token_balance: BigInt(0),
  });


  const instructionData = serializeUserAccount(userAccount);
  const instructionDataBuffer = Buffer.from(instructionData);

  const userAccountPubkey = await PublicKey.createWithSeed(publicKey, "user-account", PROGRAM_ID);

  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: userAccountPubkey,
      basePubkey: publicKey,
      seed: "user-account",
      space: 1000,
      lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(1000),
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    new TransactionInstruction({
      keys: [{ pubkey: userAccountPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }],
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
      data: instructionDataBuffer,
    })
  );

  //const sig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, []);
  //  console.log('Signature:', sig);

  try{
    const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');
    alert(`User registration as ${userType === UserType.Creator ? "Creator" : "Viewer"}`);
  }catch(error){
    console.error("Error registration user:", error);
    alert("Failed to register user. See console for details.");
  }

}```[![This is what I am getting in console][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/19nyfgo3.png

